# Insert a node to graph in its best place, not at end of graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, traveling-salesman, insertion-order

Suppose I have a `list=[2,5,7]` (representing a visit order of cities). I want to insert node `6` to this list (or Graph); however, I'm looking for the best place of insertion (in terms of total cost of `list`). For instance Cost of `list1=[2,6,5,7]` is lower than cost of `list2=[2,5,7,6]`. The Cost function is the distance between nodes. For instance, `Cost[2,6,5,7] = Distance[2][6] + Distance[6][5] + Distance[5][7]`

Is there any fast way of doing this? Is there any built-in function in Networkx (like `nx.dijkstra_path_length(G, i, j, 'weight')` which calculates shortest path before insertion) or any other package? Please note that `list=[2,5,7]` can be considered as a graph and easily generated by Networkx `(2---5---7)`

P.S: I will provide a toy-sized instance below: `a=[6,10]` and `list=[2,5,7]` are my inputs. I want to add all nodes in `a` (6 and 10) to the best places in `list` (like adding a node to a TSP tour). There are two possible positions for insertion of 6 in `list`. 
A: between `2` and `5` 
B: between `5` and `7`. 
Since `Cost[2,6,5,7] < Cost[2,5,7,6]`, option A provides lowest cost. 
Now `list=[2,6,5,7].` 
Again for insertion of node `10`, all three possible places should be checked 
A: between `2` and `6` 
B: between `6` and `5` 
C: between `5` and `7`. 
Output would be a list like `[2,6,5,10,7]`

Comment: Can you give a clearer example of what you're trying to do?  So give us the full input (presumably including a graph) and what you want the output to be?

Comment: I'm looking for fastest way of "Cheapest Insertion" (or "Best Insertion") algorithm. I will provide a toy-sized instance below: 

`a=[6,10]` and `list=[2,5,7]` are my inputs. I want to add nodes `6` and `10` to the `list` (like adding a node to a TSP tour). There are two possible positions for insertion 
A: between 2 and 5 B: between 5 and 7. Since `Cost[2,6,5,7] < Cost[2,5,7,6]` option A provides lowest cost. Now `list=[2,6,5,7]`. Again for insertion of node `10` all three possible places should be checked A: between 2 and 6 B between 6 and 5 C: between 5 and 7. `output=[2,6,5,10,7]`

Comment: There is a function in networkx called (dijkstra_path_length). Is there any similar function to do this best insertion algorithm? If not, what would be the efficient way of doing this? (instead of nested loops)

Comment: What is your cost function?

Comment: The Cost function is the distance between nodes. So `Cost[2,6,5,7] = Distance[2][6] + Distance[6][5] + Distance[5][7]`

Comment: Please edit the extra information into your question so that the question is self-contained without reading the comments.  Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: You're clearly thinking of this as a graph problem.  But there is no graph in your question or comments.  We need a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, Joel. I edited the main question. I hope you can understand it know.